# UITableView Cell Identifier field is disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am new to XCode and am doing an apple tutorial 'Start Developing iOS apps Today' in XCode 5.0.  In storyboard I have created a table view controller and created some cells and marked the Content of the tableview as 'Dynamic Prototypes'. The tutorial wants me to set the Identifier of the first cell so that I can then use this identifier in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as a parameter for `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.
The problem is that I am unable to set the cells identifier as it is disabled and the field contains the text 'Reuse Identifier'.
Can I enable the identifier field or, if not, will this cell have a special identifier that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is disabled ? It might look like so, but you can still input some text. "Reuse Identifier" is a placeholder, it's just there until you type something, so you know what to type in the field.

If it looks like this, it's perfectly normal :

[image: Screenshot]

Simply click on the textfield, and start typing your custom identifier.

Comment: @crackles I wouldn't say that, you're just new to Xcode ! ;)